# Using Visual Studio Code, how can I change the Index page height and width size?

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to change the web page width but unable to do so. How can I do this using Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

You can write inline css for your page if you dont want to create a seperate css file.

```
<body width ="write desired width"> </body>
```

As an example

```
<body width ="100px"> </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, so I attempted to do this in the .css file but the index page has not changed size. Any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Inline styling require   tag inside of the  tag

```
<body style="width=100px;">
...
```

And if you like to test what's going on:  you can add update like as this:

`<body style="width=100px;border:1px solid red;">`

Quick CodePen sample is [here](https://codepen.io/aobasar/pen/oNqzByL)